# MS SQL Server - (Current date -1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dateadd

I'm looking for something similar to - `DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())`

To use like this - `and sale.OrderDateKey >= (current DATE(without time) - 1 day)`

**e.g.**  `and sale.OrderDateKey >= '2018-07-22'`

Comment: What is wrong with using the dateadd -1?

Comment: DATEADD(day,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

Comment: @DavidG The question is not duplicated, as you can see, I specify that I need date WITHOUT  time and so one, yes you are right, that they are similar, but bot the same, as the "similar" answer is not answering my question.

Comment: @DavidG then I found that need to use format 112, an so one...... Any way I could midufy my question to make it understandeble, and unique?

Comment: @MatSnow What should I do to improve this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cast datetime(GETDATE()) to date

```
sale.OrderDateKey >=  DATEADD(day,-1,CAST(GETDATE() as date))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
and sale.OrderDateKey >= CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 120)
```